# Google Calendar API is not showing event list

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps

I am trying to retrieve events from a Google  calendar. I am calling this URL:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/riteshmehandiratta%40gmail.com/events

Authorization:  Bearer ya29.AHES6ZSvz3O7V2p7z_k_ZWAiUZqWX35Eyx5V_J4XC5pVSNxLjS6CNzQ
```

and I am getting this response:

```json
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"ZrhdJMCgpoUK_a5fT7XOC6xn46g/_4_AQ2FVvAtAEiDFDj8_pH_usqc\"",
 "summary": "riteshmehandiratta@gmail.com",
 "updated": "2013-02-18T03:45:37.728Z",
 "timeZone": "Asia/Calcutta",
 "accessRole": "owner",
 "defaultReminders": [
  {
   "method": "email",
   "minutes": 10
  },
  {
   "method": "popup",
   "minutes": 10
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "CigKGnR0ZG1xbjAyNHQ1Y3RycjYwY2x0ZGxtcTk0GAEggIDA28aNo-cT"
}
```

There are many events in the calendar for the past, future and for the current date.

Why its not giving the calendar event list?

Answer (score 0):

there is definitely something weird here, in the response you are posting, i see you are getting the *nextPageToken* tag, so there actually ARE more results, you can call the next result "page", using a similar request with the variable *pageToken* added, something like

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/riteshmehandiratta%40gmail.com/events?pageToken=CigKGnR0ZG1xbjAyNHQ1Y3RycjYwY2x0ZGxtcTk0GAEggIDA28aNo-cT
```

that way you'll get more results.

Anyway this is weird because the *nextPageToken* doesn't show up  if you don't limit the query with some variable like *maxResults*. Please check if you are not limiting the query somewhere else.

Maybe you can find useful for making test, the [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list), that has at the bottom a request form that can build the query for you.

Hope this helps, regards

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same problem. Sometimes the list API will return an empty item list with a nextPageToken, even if I did not limit the number of responses. The solution is to check if there is a nextPageToken, and make another request for the next page until you get a response without a nextPageToken.

Answer (score -2):

I looped through the requests until there wasn't a nextPage token, appending the event lists to a local list, and this provided a full list of the events.