# Events created with Calendar API not showing up in the calendar

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I'm experimenting with Google Calendar API in an attempt to set reminders for users. I think setting a calendar event and setting a reminder to it could do what I need.

I'm using this sample code from google to try the API, I'm getting Back the description of the event I created. But if I sign in to my Google calendar I can't see the event there.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Calendar API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Google Calendar API Quickstart</p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID ='781531190408-u3gh34li8b0um74r11m8hsbcofbpj4jf.apps.googleusercontent.com';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          listUpcomingEvents();
          // Refer to the JavaScript quickstart on how to setup the environment:
// https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js
// Change the scope to 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar' and delete any
// stored credentials.

var event = /*{
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2017-07-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2017-07-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  'attendees': [
    {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
    {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'}
  ],
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': false,
    'overrides': [
      {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
      {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}
    ]
  }
};*/{
  "reminders": {
    "useDefault": false,
    "overrides": [
      {
        "method": "email",
        "minutes": 15
      },
      {
        "method": "popup",
        "minutes": 15
      },
      {
        "method": "popup",
        "minutes": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2017-07-12T10:30:00.0z"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2017-07-12T11:30:00.0z"
  },
  "description": "Just a test description "
};

var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({

  'calendarId': 'primary',
  'resource': event
});

request.execute(function(event) {
  appendPre('Event created: ' + event.description);
});
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
       * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
       * appropriate message is printed.
       */
      function listUpcomingEvents() {
        gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
          'calendarId': 'primary',
          'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
          'showDeleted': false,
          'singleEvents': true,
          'maxResults': 10,
          'orderBy': 'startTime'
        }).then(function(response) {
          var events = response.result.items;
          appendPre('Upcoming events:');

          if (events.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
              var event = events[i];
              var when = event.start.dateTime;
              if (!when) {
                when = event.start.date;
              }
              appendPre(event.description + ' (' + when + ')')
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
          }
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the [JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) and insert an event using this [sample code](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples) and I got a successful response. Maybe the problem is how you handle your authorization. You may check this [tutorial](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2011/12/using-new-js-library-to-unlock-power-of.html).

Some additional references:

- [Need good example: Google Calendar API in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607465/need-good-example-google-calendar-api-in-javascript/11622475#11622475)
- [Events added through Google API PHP client not showing in Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251279/events-added-through-google-api-php-client-not-showing-in-calendar)
- [Google Calendar Api is not showing event list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929221/google-calendar-api-is-not-showing-event-list)

Comment: I think the event gets created because the other functions that pulls the upcoming events pulls the event that I just created. The problem is I cant see this event on my calendar. Should I not be seeing it among other stuff on my calendar like people's birthdays?